# drag and drop items between Recyclerview (Listview) in android

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I am currently developing an android application in which i need to implement drag and drop items between Recyclerview (ListView).

I need to implement feature like PMTool Jira.

Also find a library to drag and drop in android [here](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView)

I have successfully implemented the scenario which is mentioned in above link but i need to perform drag and drop between RecyclerView (ListView) which is not same in size and can perform drag and drop anywhere in a screen where RecyclerView(ListView)s are.

want to achieve like this [image]

if anyone have implemented the same or any idea regarding this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drag Shadow Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.DragShadowBuilder) technique for this case (to move item across recyclerview). Please refer [this](https://github.com/pooja-gaikwad15/recyclerview-list-drag-and-drop) library